# *Actual* exact MySQL fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

So I'm having some difficulty creating exact searches in MySQL fulltext.

In my database, I'm trying to find jobs with a specific keyword in its title.

So I might try

```
WHERE MATCH(jobTitle) AGAINST ('"fs sales"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, this finds matches on `"sales"`, not `"fs sales"`

How can I ensure that `"fs sales"` matches EXACTLY on `"fs sales"` and not `"sales"`?

Table is InnoDB for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fs" is probably excluded from the search as too short.

Check the value of `innodb_ft_min_token_size` and manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

You have to rebuild the index after changing that variable.

Comment: Marking this is the answer due to being the exact issue. `innodb_ft_min_token_size` was set to 3, so 'fs' was too short.

Answer (score 1):

Your query *should* work.  My guess, though is that you did not change the minimum word length, so "fs" was never indexed.  See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) for information on this.

Other possibilities are that there are other characters in the text, perhaps characters you do not see.

You might try this

```
select t.*
from (select . . .
      WHERE MATCH(jobTitle) AGAINST ('+fs +sales' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
     ) t
where jobTitle like '%fs sales%';
```

This only does the `like` on the returned set from the match.

However, my best guess is that `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is set to its default value of 3, so "fs" is not being indexed.

Comment: `innodb_ft_min_token_size` was set to 3, so 'fs' was too short. `ft_min_word_len` was set to 1 so I knew that wasn't the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The subquery is unnecessary:  `SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST('+sales' ...) AND  ... LIKE '%fs sales%';`

Comment: @RickJames . . . Are you certain the `MATCH()` is performed first in this case?  I don't mean "Oh, it always seems to go first".  But is it *guaranteed* to be first?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Long ago, in an ancient MyISAM world, I believe I heard that the FT part always came first.  If they have changed that for InnoDB, I don't know.  It makes sense that FT would come first, since it is often very selective.  I don't know if it might use "index merge", which might be a decent alternative.

Comment: @RickJames . . . It *totally* makes sense that `match()` comes first.  I've just never come across a reference in the documentation that guarantees that it is processed first -- or at least suggests it when the `where` clause consists only of `and`ed conditions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
 select col1, col2 from table_name where text_column like '%fs sales%'
```

this will return all the records having fs sales in them..

Comment: Thats no good - While it would work, it forces a full table scan which is slow performance (something that is not acceptable in this system)